# External HDD detected, but cannot be mounted

Tags: 16.04, mount, external-hdd

I am trying to copy some data over from an external hard drive to my computer through a USB cable. It seems like the device is visible, but the partition table is unknown.

Here is the output to lsblk, fdisk and parted. My external device is `sda`

```
$ lsblk
...
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   977M  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 952.4G  0 part /
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ...

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1050624 1998407679 1997357056 952.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1998407680 2000408575    2000896   977M Linux swap

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500076404736 bytes, 976711728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

```
$ sudo parted -l
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: BUFFALO HD-LXU3 (scsi)                                             
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1023GB  1023GB  ext4
 3      1023GB  1024GB  1024MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

I also checked the drive with the `Disk` utility, but under volumes I only get "500 GB unknown" along with:

```
Size: 500 GB (500,076,404,736 bytes)
Device: /dev/sda
Contents: Unknown
```

As for trying to mount the device:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda /media/nananana
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was the original fs type of the HDD? It may be dead try running `smartctl -t <long><short> /dev/sda` long and short are the "running lenght" respectivley

Comment: `Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label` .. your system don't recognise the disk label. Where where the disk and data created ? From Ubuntu it looks like a new unformated disk.

Comment: @j-money Thanks for the tip. No errors were detected though.

Comment: @SorenA, yeah, that's my impression as well but there is certainly data on the disk. I got it from one of our clients and they said it worked well on Linux. The only thing different is the cable I use to connect to it, but if that was the problem I shouldn't see the device at all I guess.